# How to contact the IRS to determine if your taxes have been filed by a CPA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

As a follow-up to my other question:  [How can I avoid being fined or penalized because my accountant might have failed to file my taxes on time?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30071/how-can-i-avoid-being-fined-or-penalized-because-my-accountant-might-have-failed)

I have not received any contact from my CPA other than last week he said "they will be done Friday."  I checked http://www.irs.gov and without knowing the "refund amount" (which I expect to be negative) I can't seem to find any resources on how to determine if my taxes have been filed.

How do I go about finding out if my refund has been filed if I don't know what my "refund" or "amount owed" is?

Comment: Good luck contacting the IRS this time of year. Even the IRS is saying that they are likely only going to answer 60% of calls from taxpayers this year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know the refund amount - how exactly do you expect anything to be filed? The CPA cannot file anything on your behalf without you signing [form 8879](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/f8879--2013.pdf) - which has the refund amount printed on it.

You should have signed this form and received a copy of the tax return, otherwise - the CPA cannot file anything.

In case your CPA is a crook and filed your tax return without your authorization - you'll see it on your IRS transcript. I wrote a [detail article on how to get that](http://littleadvisor.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/great-new-service-from-the-irs-get-your-account-transcripts-online/). However, CPA doing so may very easily lose the license, so I doubt that it happened in your case.

More likely than not your CPA just didn't do it on time. If it results in any penalties for you - you can demand the CPA to cover it (but not the actual tax - that is yours). If you're due refund there will be no penalties.

Comment: I think the transcript might be sufficient.  Is there any other way to contact the IRS to check if he might have filed an extension if it is safe to assume he did not file them yet?

Comment: @user14549 what will it give you?

Comment: If an extension was filed then I don't need to worry so much right now.  If an extension was not filed, I need to find another accountant ASAP.

Comment: I'd say you need to find another accountant either way...