# CPA did my taxes but never filed

Tags: united-states, taxes

My CPA did my taxes,(I have the copies), but never e-filed. I have contacted the IRS, and they have nothing on record. I am expecting a refund.  I never received it because of this.  What do I do? Do I have to redo my taxes myself? Plug in all his numbers in something like Turbo Tax? I already paid him.  I have been trying every day to contact him, but he never gets back to me.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30071/how-can-i-avoid-being-fined-or-penalized-because-my-accountant-might-have-failed

Comment: I think this is sufficiently different, given there are no penalties due in this situation, but good to link.

Comment: What I heard once: Get damaged.  What were you going to use the refund for?  To buy XYZ.  Okay. Try to buy XYZ without that refund money.  Fail.  Go ahead, apply for a loan and get denied (even if you had no need for the loan).  Or do something else; proceed to experience a failure of some sort.  Get inconvenienced.  Then, you can say that you experienced an actual hardship, besides just feeling mentally less satisfied.  This can be good, because courts are more likely to compensate for actual hardships that happened.  Even if you don't sue, having that card up your sleeve might be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are owed a refund, then there is no negative consequence to filing late aside from a delay in receiving your funds, you have up to 3 years to claim a refund.

If you have copies (and believe the CPA prepared your return properly), you can make a copy and mail that in, probably the easiest path forward if the return is complete but un-filed. Otherwise you'd have to re-enter things or pay someone else to file the return.

Addresses vary, select your state from the following and pick the address from the left column on the subsequent page for the appropriate form:

[IRS: Where to File Paper Tax Returns With or Without a Payment](https://www.irs.gov/uac/where-to-file-paper-tax-returns-with-or-without-a-payment)

Edit: The suggested possible [duplicate](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30071/how-can-i-avoid-being-fined-or-penalized-because-my-accountant-might-have-failed) has good info on what action you might take against the CPA, but if all you care about is filing and getting your refund, then the above should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Print your return and follow the instructions to mail it in.  If you suspect your CPA may be a fraudster, double check to make sure he didn't enter his own Routing Number and Account number in the refund portion of your return or the IRS will send your money to his bank acccount!!!  Verify Lines 73 - 75 on your 1040 form (the first form on your tax return) are ok and you will receive your refund in the mail or as an electronic transfer.

Comment: The IRS already said they have nothing.  Your scenario contradicts that.

Comment: @donjuedo IRS have nothing -> print your return and mail it to them. How is that contradictory?

Comment: My mistake.  I thought you were saying the CPA might have entered his own routing number and account *and sent it in*.  That last part is not in your answer -- I didn't realize I had inferred it.

Comment: This does remind me of a real estate attorney named Michael Jordan.  He cleaned out his trust account (client money), faked his death (coastal South Carolina boating "accident"), and fled to Canada.  He was caught at the border with his mistress.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding to make sure the routing and account number are your's was good input, even if you "don't think he filed"... maybe he's waiting to file it or just filed it, for some fraudulent reason.....